How to link URL without using packages (in Lua(La)TeX)?
How could I link a URL without using any packages (i.e. either in plain TeX or using Lua(La)TeX)?
I am compiling with Lua(La)TeX.

With LaTeX, hyperref is barely a package. Yes, you import it with \usepackage{hyperref}, but it's been maintained as a part of the LaTeX project for 5 years, it's used in almost every document, and pretty much every package is compatible with it. Now, if you're using Plain TeX, then that's different, but with the recent pdfmanagement additions, I doubt that a Plain solution would work in LaTeX. You should probably edit the question to specify either Plain or LaTeX.

\pdfextension startlink user{/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(https://www.example.com)>>}  some text \pdfextension endlink with luatex, with plain use \pdfstartlink ... \pdfendlink.

Just as a note: For tex (aka classic plainTeX with DVI output) hyperbasic.tex (or hyperbasic.new.tex) from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/hypertex/tanmoy could be interesting. But AFAIK it has never been adapted to work with pdftex or luatex. And miniltx is not enough to be able to load hyperref with plainTeX.

@MaxChernoff even if hyperref is maintained by the LaTeX team: it is quite a monster with lots of side effects (e.g. it will also turn all references into links) and so can be too much if you only want an url. The primitives for links do not clash with the pdf management (but are not really needed as there are abstracted versions in l3pdfannot).

Could you clarify if you are using LaTeX or plain TeX - the tags suggest the latter, the title the former.
